# Filter data from two tables having many to many relation django

Tags: django, database, python-3.x, django-models, django-queryset

I am new to python Django. I have a scenario where I want to filter out data of slots from the slot table of a specific customer. Tables are connected using third table appointments. In the appointment table, I am storing the customer id and slot id associated with that customer. How to filter out customers all slots associated with it?

[image]

This is a diagram of tables and their relation with each other.  Please help me out to solve it. I know by using join in SQL I get data. But I want to filter data in python Django so how I can apply joins in Django to filter data. I googled a lot but didn't get any proper answer. Please Provide a proper explanation with your answer.

Comment: Can you post your `models.py` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand, You want to list out all slot for the particular customer.

Say example **cust_id = 1** then there are **slot_id 1,2,3** associated with that customer in appointment table.

I would do something like this,

```
# Retreive all slot id for the customer with id = 1
slot_ids = Appointment.objects.filter(cust_id=1).values('id')

# Get all slots related to the customer 
slots = Slot.objects.filter(id__in=slot_ids)
```

**Remember you should use values()** and retrieve specific column for **id__in** to work with.

Check here for more info https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/